# Using a lot of String Comparisons... Is there a better method than simply .equals()?

Tags: java, string

I am writing a program that is data intensive and requires a very considerable amount of String comparisons however I feel like `.equals()` is a very costly method. Is there a more efficient method of comparing strings?

Edit:

I have two csv files that contain client related information. In these two csv files the data recorded is not the same except for name and address. (This is not really even guaranteed but that's an entirely different problem) I am tasked with making a program to identify the matches in the clients over these two csv files then combine the information for the given client and output a master csv file with all data from the two files present for the given client. I was asking about the equals method because the only way I saw of tackling this problem is by doing a great deal of string comparisons along the way. My approach is going to be to develop a very specific sort on the csv prior to entering the program that essentially puts the last name (or the address I haven't figured out which one will be better) in alphabetical order then running a binary search like algorithm on the clients or some sort of pointer driven search that would look for the desired client via last name and address. This was all going to be done after I had read the two csv file and essentially parsed the info into a client object. After all of your comments it looks like my question is not really about the string .equals() method but rather about is there a more efficient manner of comparing and compiling the two client objects without having to iterate through both csv files.

Comment: Comparing strings to what end?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing.  What would you have in mind?

Comment: You need to provide more information. There may be better solutions, but none that apply in a generic sense to any situation.

Comment: The problem is I have a large client list where some clients may be actually the same person and just have moved to a new address or the person inputting the data put their first name in wrong ect. So my initial approach is looking over their last names, among other pieces of info to figure out if this person is the same as another person and thus a duplicate.

Comment: And why do you think `equals()` is what is slowing everything down? Take a look at the implementation.

Comment: Address/name matching is a lot more complicated than lower-casing and comparing.

Answer (score 1):

No. The fastest (and only reasonable) way to compare Strings is with `.equals()`.

You might need to rethink your program and see if there's an alternative to comparing a ton of Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup of a String to find equality with one or more of them from those in a list should not be done by comparing them one by one. A HashMap will quickly identify a small potentially equal subset.

Redesign the implementation of your Client List. Add a

```
Map<Name,Set<Client>> last2client
```

and other similar indices.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on alot of factors ... where are you getting your client list from ?

From an excel sheet perhaps ??or from a text file ??  The reason I am asking is unless your list is hardcoded in the program (high unlikely) loading the names cell by cell from an excel sheet is what takes a humongous amount of time. No of need to find a way to import them all in a single read operation (cant help here cause it depends on your sheet layout)and start string manupulation AFTER THE ENTIRE data set is in memory. That way the loop will progress much fastet, but initializing and allocating resources along with hard disk access every single time in the iteration is what makes this take for ever, not the equals.
Just for arguments sake (I am not sure of this and would appreciate confirmations or correction) i think operations on Byte Arrays may be faster than strings if you know how to handle them and if the strings are very long like 25 plus words, but in your case don't bother .equals is the only reasonable way like Anubian Noob said.

Anyway I think that sorting out the array before you start comparisons will help alot in reducing the computation time. You could cut down on computation by only invoking the .equals operations on strings with similar .lenght() they can't be equal if they don't have the same length ... length is much faster and you will have eliminated at least 50% of your .equals operations.

So my final advice is:
1) Load enter data set in memory before string operations 
2) sort the array alphabetically
3) if lengths are equal, invoke .equal, else check the next string.

hope this helps in anyway

Comment: I am trying to parse the data from a  two csv files. The csv files contain data on a client(name) along with demographic data(address) and other info pertaining to the transaction. The two csv files, however do not contain the same extra information except for name and address, so the only hope on generating a match is via last name and address. I am trying to write a program that takes these two csv files as inputs and uses their data to link the clients from one file to the other then output a master csv file that contains all the information present in both csv files.